# Unable to get time difference between to pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a couple of columns. Two of which are start_time and end_time. In those columns the values look like - *2020-01-04 01:38:33 +0000 UTC*

I am not able to create a datetime object from these strings because I am not able to get the format right -

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000 UTC")
```

I also tried using *`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss %z UTC`* as a format

This gives the error -

```
ValueError: time data '2020-01-04 01:38:33 +0000 UTC' does not match format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000 UTC' (match)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the proper timestamp format that `to_datetime` will recognize

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000 UTC")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some notes below about this problem:

**1. About your error**

> This gives the error -

You have parsed a wrong datetime format that will cause the error. For correct format check this one https://strftime.org/. Correct format for this problem would be: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z UTC"`

**2. Pandas limitation with timezone**

Parsing UTC timezone as `%z` doesn't working on pd.Series (it only works on index value). So if you use this, it will **not work**:

```
df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.startTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z UTC", utc=True)
```

**Solution** for this is using python built-in library for inferring the datetime data:

```
from datetime import datetime
f = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z UTC")
df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.startTime.apply(f), utc=True)
```

@fmarm answer only help you dealing with date and hour data, not UTC timezone.